# JBoss AS 7.2, static resource URLs are corrupted

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, jenkins, war

I have just started to use JBoss AS, and Jenkins 1.539 is the first thing I'm trying to deploy.

**Problem is:** Non of the static contect are loaded by the browser. No CSS, No Images...
When I look at the source code in the `href` attributes, for example, instead of:

```
/jenkins/css/style.css
```

The URL is:

```
/jenkins/static/03bf67c8/css/style.css
```

Same thing with other static resources.

- This problem didn't use to happen in Tomcat.
- I tried deploying the sample WAR file from Apache Tomcat website into JBoss to see if the problem still exists. *It didn't*! Static content (the Tomcat logo) was loaded and the URL was clean.
- I tried deploying the exploded WAR file of jenkins into JBoss. The deployment was successful, though the problem was persistent.

Correct me if I'm wrong; but I just have the feeling that the problem is not with jenkins and something should be done in JBoss. Some config... something... That's why I didn't mention Jenkins is the question title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually [the problem was from Jenkins](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20163):

The static/XXXXXX is [the Jenkins development rule](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Hyperlinks+in+HTML). Nonetheless, a ClassDefNotFound exception happened when processing the URL.

Downgraded to the latest stable version. the problem was solved.